# Fix UIButton on top of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiscrollview

I'm trying to figure out how to overlay a UIButton on top of a UIScrollView. Basically the user would be able to use the scrollview normally. But a button in the top right of the scrollview would remain in a fixed position. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add the UIButton as a subView of the UIScrollView, but instead of "self.view"

[image: Your hierarchy should look like this. Notice how the button is now in the drop down for the scroll view. Just drag the button out]

Comment: Is their a way to do this in IB? I tried dragging a button on top of the UIScrollView (making it a subview of the scrollview), but how do I add it to self.view? I'd rather not do this programatically if possible.

Comment: Forgive the newbie question shabzco, but how did you include the image?

Comment: @MobileVet You can just click "edit" to view how he did it... Just dont change anything in the answer.

Comment: amazing.
i would like to do this programmatically though, how would you do that in code? it seems my attempt to add scrollview before add the button were not the solution

Answer (score 3):

In the InterfaceBuilder there will be a Hierarchal list of items you put in your view, drag the button from being a view belonging to the scrollView to belonging to the view containing the subview.

Your view hierarchy will look like the following

```
mainView

|

----Button

|

----ScrollView
```

Instead of

```
mainView

|

----ScrollView

  |

  ----Button
```

basically It means both your button and your ScrollView will both be subViews of the exact same mainView. If your scrollView is the mainView put an empty UIView above the scrollView and insert the UIButton & UIScrollView into that

Answer (score 2):

IB is a little finicky when dropping new views directly on the 'fake' interface.  What you will need to do is go over to the left in the list of views and select your button view.  Now drag it up to below the 'self.view' or whatever is your top level view.

YOu should notice as you raise it up and down in the list that a light blue line will appear.  The width corresponds to 'subview' or 'parent' view connection.  Play with it a bit to see the difference.

When you feel comfortable, you should be able to place the Button in the 'self.view', not as a subview of the scroll view.  Additionally, if you want it to appear on TOP (physical 'Z level') you will need it to be below the scroll view in the list.  ( this points out a subtle problem with CStreet's solution)

Comment: +1 for great tip about placing button below scroll view in the list, it was what I was looking for :)